# DTSRUN execution ready but not exiting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

I have an old application environment where DTS Jobs are triggered by a SQL Server 2000 Agent Job. The Agent Jobs seem to run endless.

I ran the same call from command line and I found that the DTS Job seems to have successfully finished but is not exiting.

Can you help me?

I call the DTS Jobs as a CmdExec within the Agent Job. My call looks like

```
DTSRun /S "(local)" /N "##NameOfDtsPackage##" /E
```

[CMD: OS is set to German. The last line says 'package execution completed'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WAeX.png) but dtsrun is not exiting.

I know DTS is very outdated but sadly there is no possibility to replace because the client needs it.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying a lot. It seems like the ActiveX Script in the DTS Package is not returning the right exit code. I can not figure out why because the exact same package is running on another machine. In fact I only wanted create a backup environment.

Because the script was only for file copy I replaced it with a cmdexec script. Now the DTS package runs successfully and afterwards the cmdexec starts the file copy.